# cannot use keyboard's numpad to input digit

Tags: common-lisp, xlib

Using stumpwm, I cannot input digit in Evaling window using the numpad (NumLock is already on). By hacking the input.lisp,  i found the following result:

The #'read-key-and-selection will return different value for primary pad and numpad.

```
             1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8          9
primary pad  (10 . 16) (11 . 16) (12 . 16) (13 . 16) (14 . 16) (15 . 16) (16 . 16) (17 . 16) (18 . 16)
numpad       (87 . 16) (88 . 16) (89 . 16) (83 . 16) (84 . 16) (85 . 16) (79 . 16) (80 . 16) (81 . 16)
```

It causes #'process-input regard the numpad input as :error .

```
(defun read-key-or-selection ()
    (loop for ev = (xlib:process-event *display* :handler #'read-key-or-selection-handle-event :timeout nil) do
        (cond ((stringp ev)
            (return ev))
         ((and (consp ev)
               (eq (first ev) :key-press))
           (return (cdr ev))))))

(defun read-key-or-selection-handle-event (&rest event-slots &key display event-key &allow-other-keys)
    (declare (ignore display))
    (case event-key
        ((or :key-release :key-press)
         (apply 'input-handle-key-press-event event-slots))
        (:selection-notify
         (apply 'input-handle-selection-event event-slots))
        (t nil)))

(defun input-handle-key-press-event (&rest event-slots &key event-key root code state &allow-other-keys)
    (declare (ignore event-slots root))
    (list* event-key code state))
```

From above code, it seems there exists problem in #'xlib:process-event.  But i cannot know how to fix it ?

Please shed a light on me, thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about stumpwm, but it seems to me that this is handling raw input. You'll have to translate it to get an actual character.

Comment: What do you mean with "Small Keyboard"? Are you using an external (e.g. USB) numeric keypad or the one at the right of your keyboard?

Comment: except stumpwm, other applications work well using the freebsd 9.0 box. such a translation should not be done by user.

Answer (score 1):

find a not canonical way but it works.  https://github.com/sw2wolf/stumpwm/blob/master/input.lisp.